# Very custom screen dimensions on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, resolution, screen-capture

I'm trying to do a screencast with two screens side-by-side, each screen being square. Any tip might help.

I could use two computers and stitch the recordings together. But I would have to set the screen dimensions to something square. setResX and friends require me to reboot and turn off integrity security; same for hacking the monitor plist files (on El Capitan).

I could use one computer and have a split workspace. Still requires me to hack the screen plists or use setResX.

I could try to run OS X in VMware on OS X (how?). That gives more flexibility in setting the virtual screen I think.

Here is a nice idea, [Syphon virtual screen](https://andreacremaschi.github.io/Syphon-virtual-screen/). Doesn't work on El Capitan!

I dislike all of the above. Anyone have better ideas?

Comment: So I am not quite understanding you. You want to do a screen capture with two of your monitors in the video. Your monitors, however, are not 16:9 ratio but you do not want to use setResX? Just trying to understand what you are trying to achieve before I answer. You might want to edit your question to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: @Mekul - I want to do a screencast with two applications next to eachother. Each application window should be square and preferably fullscreen within that square, so the result movie is something like 2048:1024. Simply for design reasons.

Comment: None of us has either 2 x 1024x1024 or a 2048x1024 monitor. Who should watch this screencast (or use the two apps)? If both applications have application windows why don't you just position the 2 windows next to each other and generate a 16:9 (or 16:10) video? Function follows form?

Comment: I want this for design reasons, form follows form. I wanted it bad enough to ask SE for help; if I thought I could settle for something else I would have done that. . FYI - i did now carefully position the two windows to a 2048:1024 grid and made a screencast of that. I won't be able to repeat that to the pixel, tho - I was looking for a more configurable kind of setup.